# Child(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have two js files Child.js and App.js.

Child.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = (props) =>{
    <div>
        <button onClick={props.doWhatever}>{props.title}</button>
    </div>

}
export default Child;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './components/parentTochild/Child.js'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title : 'Helloooo'
  }

  changeWorld = (newTitle) => {
    this.setState = ({
      title : newTitle
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child doWhatever={this.changeWorld.bind(this , 'New world')} title={this.state.title}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

While executing this code I'm getting the error mentioned in the title. I have tried to solve it. But I couldn't figure out what's  the problem with this code.

When I removed `<Child doWhatever={this.changeWorld.bind(this , 'New world')} title={this.state.title}/>` and typed a text it showed on screen. The problem is when using the *Child* component.

Comment: You need to add return statement to `Child` or use implicit return `const Child = props => ( /* notice ( not {*/
    <div>`

Comment: It is essential to include a return statement in Child.js

Answer (score 2):

You should return some thing from child component.

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = (props) =>{
    return (
          <div>
               <button onClick={(event)=>props.doWhatever('New world')}>{props.title}</button>
          </div>
    );

}
export default Child;
```

**Updated:**

If you want to send a text with the event handler to you can do this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './components/parentTochild/Child.js'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
          title : 'Helloooo'
      };
      this.changeWorld=this.changeWorld.bind(this);
  }

  changeWorld = (newTitle) => {
    this.setState = ({
      title : newTitle
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child doWhatever={this.changeWorld} title={this.state.title}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you . The error got solved . But the onClick event not working

Comment: use this for constructor => constructor() {
        this.changeWorld = this.changeWorld.bind(this);
    } and this for calling child component => <Child doWhatever={this.changeWorld} title={this.state.title} />

Comment: change the code inside the function changeWorld as `this.setState({
      title : newTitle
    });`. Because setState is a function, you cannot assign a value as a variable

Comment: I need to pass the value "New world" through the function " changeWorld" .@jsDevia as you said tried construstor . But how to pass this value?

Comment: U want to pass the value in render time or in click event time ?

Comment: in click event time

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe it can help u, note that i send the new text from child component, but if u need to pass the text from its higher component let me know.